# Sql query that selects all inactive users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query to implement.

I have 2 tables: **user** and **login_logs** table.

The **user** table looks like this:

**id** ||  **first_name** || **last_name** ||           **email**                 || **username** || **activated**  || **suspended**

1   ||       John       ||      Dan       ||      john@whatever       ||      john1    ||     1      ||       0       ||

2   ||       Mike       ||      Hutt       ||      mike@whatever       ||      mike1    ||     1      ||       0       ||

etc.

The **login_logs** table looks like this:

**id**    ||      **login_datetime**     || **user_id**

1     || 2011-01-27 23:04:59   ||      1

2     || 2010-01-27 23:04:59   ||      2

etc.

So the **login_logs** table keeps record of when a user has logged in.

Now I want to make a query that selects all inactive users. Inactive users are:

1) users that have not logged in for 90 days

2) users that have never logged in

I have made a query that satisfies the first condition but is not completely correct:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.last_name, u.first_name, u.email,u.username

 FROM users u INNER JOIN login_logs l ON l.user_id = u.id 

 WHERE u.activated = 1 AND u.suspended = 0  AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), l.login_datetime) <= 90

 ORDER BY u.last_name, u.first_name, u.id
```

The above query is not right because if I have logged in ages ago, but also recently it treats me as an inactive user because it sees I logged in ages ago.

So I want to fix the mistake I describe above and also satisfy the second condition (Select  people that have never logged in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select u.* from user u left outer join login l
on u.id = l.user_id
where l.user_id is null
or DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), l.login_datetime) <= 90
```

Comment: This will select the same user several times if he/she logged in more than once in the last 90 days.

Comment: Thanks Sachin! Now it selects users that have never logged in.. But what about the case that  I have logged in ages ago, but also recently it treats me as an inactive user because it sees I logged in ages ago??

Answer (score 8):

First your query needs to include all users, so turn it to a LEFT JOIN.

Next your query needs to use a GROUP BY to get the MAX login time per user.

Thirdly, don't put a date function against a column - it doesn't help performance, instead index the date column and construct a date to test against.

```
SELECT u.id, u.last_name, u.first_name, u.email, u.username
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN login_logs l ON l.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.activated = 1 AND u.suspended = 0
GROUP BY u.id, u.last_name, u.first_name, u.email, u.username
HAVING IFNULL(max(l.login_datetime), 0) <= ADDDATE(CURDATE(), interval -90 day)
ORDER BY u.last_name, u.first_name, u.id
```

The last part in there `IFNULL(max(l.login_datetime), 0)` ensures that if the LEFT JOIN resulted in no record in login_logs (never logged in), it will use the date 0 to test instead, which is obviously `<= 90 days ago`; therefore the record (user) shows.

Comment: I think it works quite nicely! Thank you very much cyberwiki! Though i have to study the query since i wasnt aware of the having clause! Thanks!